# create tokens in jquery token input

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, jquery-tokeninput

Presently my jquery token input is working perfectly fine.

Am not able to create token, which is not in the list

I have seen [here](https://github.com/loopj/jquery-tokeninput/pull/219), that this functionality is implemented. But there is no documentation on how we i can use this.

Can any one help me with documentation or demo

js_js.js

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#job_skills").tokenInput("/jobs/search_job_skills", {
            theme: "facebook",
            preventDuplicates: true,
            hintText: 'Add skills need for job',
            searchingText: 'searching skills...',
            allowCreation: true,
            creationText: 'Add new element'
        });

    });
```

cons_controller.rb

```
  def search_job_skills
    search_for_json(Skill)
  end

  def search_for_json(model_search)
    @hash = []

    @search_res = model_search.where(['name LIKE ?', "#{params[:term]}%"])

    @search_res.each do |tag|
      @hash << { id: tag.id,
                 name: tag.name}
    end
    render json: @hash
  end
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Include `allowFreeTagging: true` when you initiate.

Unfortunately, the documentation hasn't been updated in a few years.

Also note that if you set `allowFreeTagging` to true, you will want to change the `tokenValue` to `"name"`, because when you save the tag on your server, you probably want to save the name, not the id.

Here is a look at my token options

```
tokenOptions = {
    allowFreeTagging: true,
    tokenValue: 'name'
}

$('input#tag-input').tokenInput('/tags.json', tokenOptions);
```

This way, when a user selects tags, the names are sent to the server, and if there are any new tag names, I simply create them server-side.

Comment: Yay! You have saved me from having to rebuild this!

Comment: @bwheeler96 Glad it helped someone, if not the OP!

Comment: Definitely. I had to do a little extra digging, I added my findings to your post. Thanks!

Comment: @bwheeler96 - Unnecessary, no? When new tags are created the `ID` and `Name` are by default set to the same value, so for your free tags, the `name` value will be returned to the server regardless of whether `tokenValue` is set to `name` or `id`. It is of course possible that you could want to return name values instead of id's for your normal tags, but that's completely separate functionality, and not related to this question. Can you clarify why you'd specifically need to do this here? Thought I'd ask before rolling back, I've probably misunderstood you! =)

Comment: Hmmm... in my experience with this, the jquery token-input was sending only the ID, making it impossible to generate new tags on the server side. You can roll back if you feel it necessary, but I think that it's more explicit this way.

Comment: Yes, but for a 'freetag' - the id is the same as the name, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, but then how do you distinguish between ID's and names? For example what if a user tags `365`, or `24/7`. This would make type identifying impossible right? Best let the DB decide the ID IMHO

Comment: Ah, I see. I personally detect this by `if (name == id)` - as I already use the `tokenValue` attribute to store other information for each token. I see what you're getting at now though!

Comment: Yea, while what I added may not be **100% necessary**, it fits nicely within the Principles Of Least Surprise

Comment: Hey buddy thank you so much i did lot of RND for customize plugin for my regular need and finally I got some part of it from here.