# How to add new tokens that are not already in the TokenInput

Tags: jquery, jquery-tokeninput

I have created a input type textbox which user can fill-in with the help of autocompletion.

For the autocomplete functionality, I have used a jQuery plugin that takes input from a given list.
When I type a word which is not in the list, it shows no results and doesn't create a token. I want to also create a token for a word that is not in input list.

My code is below:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="src/jquery.tokeninput.js"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/token-input-facebook.css" type="text/css" />   
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("input[type=button]").click(function () {
                alert("Would submit: " + $(this).siblings("input[type=text]").val());
            });
        });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <input type="text" id="demo-input-facebook-theme" name="blah2" />

        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#demo-input-facebook-theme").tokenInput([
                {id: 7, name: "Ruby"},
                {id: 11, name: "Python"},
                {id: 13, name: "JavaScript"},
                {id: 17, name: "ActionScript"},
                {id: 19, name: "Scheme"},
                {id: 23, name: "Lisp"},
                {id: 29, name: "C#"},
                {id: 31, name: "Fortran"},
                {id: 37, name: "Visual Basic"},
                {id: 41, name: "C"},
                {id: 43, name: "C++"},
                {id: 47, name: "Java"}
            ], {
                theme: "facebook"
            });
        });
        </script>     
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: could you provide fiddle?

Comment: possible duplicate of [create tokens in jquery token input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16091254/create-tokens-in-jquery-token-input)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make use of the `allowFreeTagging` option. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17346275/1768779) for more details. Make sure you've downloaded the latest version of the plugin from Github, the version hosted on loopj.com is outdated, and may or may not include the `allowFreeTagging` functionality.

Additional note: The latest version of the plugin doesn't appear to function with jQuery versions as old as 1.5.1.

Comment: where should i add allowFreeTagging:true in my Jquery ?

Comment: As an option. Replace "theme:Facebook" with "theme:facebook,allowFreeTagging:true"

Comment: @vandy - Intersting. You're using a fairly old version of jQuery, which the plugin doesn't seem to work with. Update to the latest jQuery version, and things seem to work. I've set up a working example for you here: http://jsfiddle.net/zsh5mwzx/

Comment: thanks a lot :) one more question is there any way to create new tokens after pressing spacebar.In this case new token is created after pressing enter.

Comment: Check out the tokenDelimiter option!